# I am trying to get data in google sheets from one sheet to another and manipulate the received data on the new sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet from a forms survey. The data in the sheet has the following headers:

> **B** : `Name1`,
>   **C** : `Name1_Grade`,
>   **D** : `Name1_Shoe_Size`,
>   **E** : `Name2`,
>   **F** : `Name2_Grade`,
>   **G** : `Name2_Shoe_Size`,
>   **H** : `Name3`,
>   **I** : `Nanme3_Grade`,
>   **J** : `Name3_Shoe_Size`

The response form sheet has much more data in it. So, I use a query to get this data into a new sheet, `=query('Data !B2:J150,"Select B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I where (C=4 OR F=4 OR I=4)"`.

This gets my data into the new sheet, however, once it's in the sheet I need to move all of the Names, grades and shoe size to 3 columns so the end result, once the data is on the new sheet, would look like:

```
Names   |  Grade | Shoe_Size 
John F  |  4     |  6.5
```

The formula above works, however, I need to get all the names, grades, and shoe sizes into one column. Not everyone has multiple entries. So the formula needs to be able to check if something is in the other columns. The form that generates the data is set up so that one person can fill out the form for a whole family with up to 5 kids.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in one formula?

Here is a link to a sample spreadsheet: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P9qgh0o3gjDikuaX75bBr9RyYz9ofxedAuJy0tXuRko/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you share a sheet with some sample data and an example of what you need the output to look like?

Comment: added link to sample spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P9qgh0o3gjDikuaX75bBr9RyYz9ofxedAuJy0tXuRko/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to stack the columns on top of each other. So that the data lines up column-wise.

You can do that by using braces with semicolons, like so:

```
{B2:D;E2:G;H2:J}
```

Then as [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) said, you can use `Query()`. Or you could try using the `Filter()`:

```
=filter({B2:D;E2:G;H2:J},{C2:C;F2:F;I2:I}=4)
```

Comment: Thank you player() and ADW stacking worked once i realized i needed to use Col1, Col2 vs B, D etc.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=QUERY({Data!B2:D; Data!E2:G; Data!H2:J},  
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3 
  where Col2=4", 0)
```